# Listing the names of one module into the edit section of another module using relations

Tags: php, laravel, select

Here are both the models.

**Faculty.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Faculty extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function streams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stream::class);
    }
}
```

**Stream.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stream extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function faculty()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Faculty::class);
    }

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
    }
}
```

**StreamController.php**

```
public function edit(Faculty $faculty, Stream $stream, $id)
{
    $stream = Stream::find($id);
    $faculty = Faculty::all('name', 'id');
    return view('admin.stream.edit')->with(['stream' => $stream, 'faculty' => $faculty]);
}
```

**Blade VIew**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status">Select Faculty</label>
                        <select name="faculty_id" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm">

                            @foreach($faculty as $item)
                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}" >{{ $item->name }} </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I am getting the list but what I want is to show the selected one first since this is the edit section.
How can this be achieved?
Help

Comment: Do you want to selected item in first

Comment: Yes the selected item has to be shown first on dropdown

Comment: please share your `route`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this. And you don't need to pass the `$id` Because you have the value of `$tream` already. So don't need this line `$stream = Stream::find($id);` also.

```
public function edit(Faculty $faculty, Stream $stream, $id)
{
    $stream = Stream::find($id);
    $allFaculty = Faculty::all('name', 'id');
    return view('admin.stream.edit',compact('faculty','stream','allFaculty'));
}
```

And your view update this

```
@foreach($allFaculty as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if($faculty->id==$item->id) selected @endif >{{ $item->name }} </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I always do that this style. It is the best way to perform that

Comment: sorry but it didn't work.
I am still getting the list as usual.

Comment: no errors but not getting the desired results.
Still its not selected.

Comment: please first `dd($faculty, $allFaculty)` in your controller. Then check the id is exist in `$allFaculty`

Comment: $faculty returns empty while $allfaculty has the data in it wih associated id

Comment: since I am not following the exact Route-Model Binding , so may be passing only as a parameter does not have data in it.(i dont exactly know what I just said)

Comment: I check you `Faculty $faculty` this `dd($faculty)` . If you get this value then my answer 100% works.